# Change the order in a xtab

Tags: r

For a sample `data.frame`:

```
df <- structure(list(region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), 
                     result = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), weight = c(0.126, 
                                                                                        0.5, 0.8, 1.5, 5.3, 2.2, 3.2, 1.1, 0.1, 1.3, 2.5)), .Names = c("region", 
                                                                                                                                                       "result", "weight"), row.names = c(NA, 11L), class = "data.frame")

df$region <- factor(df$region)
result <- xtabs(weight ~ region + result, data=df)
result
```

How would I go about changing the order of the `xtab` (I don't want to switch the axes which I asked previously)?  For example ensuring 1 was always the first `result` or `b` was the first region.

If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate it.  I am doing some followup statistics on this data and I need to ensure my values are the right way round.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following, using `relevel`, which resets the base level of a factor:

```
df$region <- relevel(df$region, "b")  
xtabs(weight ~ region + result, data=df)
```

Perhaps the best way to do this if you want to order multiple levels is to set these up initially when first using `factor`:

```
df$region2 <- df$region <- factor(df$region, levels=c("b", "c", "a"))
```

or whatever order you want.

Comment: Thanks @Imo.  How is best to deal with the numeric 'result' column?  Obviously relevel only works with factor variables?  Should I convert this to factor or is there an easier way?

Comment: If your goal is to use this variable to tabulate, then that's what I would recommend. If your dataset isn't very big, you could create a throw-away factor variable specifically for this task.